# How to have asset_path return an absolute URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

How can you get asset_path to return an absolute URL?

I need the absolute URL for a meta tag like so:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= asset_path('logo_400x200.jpg') %>" />
```

The problem with asset_path here is that it outputs a URL with "`//site.com/logo_400x200.jpg`" and the meta tag needs an absolute path.

Any ideas on how to get an absolute path with the Rails asset_path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `asset_url`

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<%=asset_url('logo_400x200.jpg') %>" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [asset_url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url) to have the protocol added as well.